# Regular expression to extract date format e.g Wednesday, April 25 2012

Tags: java, regex

Could you please help with a RE that will extract Date in HTML stream.
e.g needed date is  `Wednesday, April 25 2012`

Thanks

Comment: @RezaSanaie Yes, I have, what do you think? We know your type.. *upsetP

Comment: @MikeMcMahon, thanks for your help,  tried `(?:(?:[1]{1}\\d{1}\\d{1}\\d{1})|(?:[2]{1}\\d{3})))(?![\\d]` but the behaviour is eratic. I need to extract a valid date from am HTML stream. So I do not have the physical date object to manipulate. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to capture the day of the week since that is easily calculated...although you could check for inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday),?\s+(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s+[0-3]?[0-9],?\s+[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

But note that it will also find invalid dates, like ones with `February 31`.

Comment: It also finds Sunday, January 00 0000, and Saturday, December 39 2999 (and everybody knows December 39, 2999 falls on a Wednesday).